# Symfony2 - ChoiceType - get choice list from JSON without JS

Tags: json, forms, symfony, dropdownchoice

I have a `JSON` file with all world languages and would like to put them into choices array inside `ChoiceType` form field.

```
$builder->add('languages', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array()
))
```

My `JSON` file is stored: `projectname/web/bundles/index/json/languages.json`

Is it possible to achieve it without writing `JS` / `AJAX`?

**P.S.** `EventListeners` or other alternatives that `Symfony2` provides suits me well.

Comment: Do you have access from the json file inside your php files?

Comment: @goto Yes json file is stored in my project directory. I updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reach the file with DIR, since I dont' know where the php file with builder is located, it could looks like:

```
 $builder->add('languages', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => json_decode(
            //if builder is in controller, this should work
            file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../../web/bundles/index/json/languages.json'),
            true)
    ));
```